# how can I update THREE.Sprite color

Tags: three.js, sprite

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yeehawjared/3xmfrojk/)

I create a material with a default color, in this case `0xffffff`.

Then later, I want to change the color.  I can't figure out where to change it - `particle.color = 0xffffff * Math.random();` doesn't work.  There is no `particle.color`, but there is a `particle.material.color`, which if I change gives me an error.

Do I need to create new materials for every sprite?  Is there a way I can simply change the color of a THREE.Sprite?

```
var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        program: function (context) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true);
            context.fill();
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        particle = new THREE.Sprite(material);
        particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.normalize();
        particle.position.multiplyScalar(Math.random() * 10 + 450);
        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 20;
        particle.color = 0xffffff * Math.random();
        scene.add(particle);
    }
```

Comment: Refer to the three.js examples:  http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_particles_random.html

Comment: thanks, they create random colors on creation.  I figured it out though after looking at the objects a little more closely.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`particle.material.color = new THREE.Color(0x0066CC);`

or

`particle.material.color.set(0x0066CC);` Threejs: R.73

from the docs:
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color

Comment: Do you really want to create a new object? Why not `material.color.set( 0xff0000 )`?

Comment: @WestLangley isn't it color.setHex (0xff0000) ?

Comment: @WestLangley yes, it works, I was confused about that. Sorry !